# Copy PST file off a network share

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm trying to copy a pst file off a network share, but it is in use. I don't have access to the computer. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately no.

You need to either close on the client (e.g. shutting down Outlook) or on the server by closing the client connection (which could leave the PST corrupt).